# OAuth2 and JWT with JPA Authentication in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-data-jpa

I have implemented a spring boot application with spring security and OAuth2 with Jwt. User information has been stored in oracle 11g for authentication and authorization and Spring Jpa is used to connect with the database. I have faced some problems during the implementation of this application.

1. I have used the following dependency for OAuth2 and a lot of classes and annotations that come with below dependency are deprecated.

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
     </dependency>
```

example

[image]

if there any alternative way or new dependency available for OAuth2?

2. Public key and Private keys have been generated by using PuTTygen and public and private keys are stored in some locations on the local computer. I need to know that can I read these files through the configuration file by using any property or should I copy public key and private key and past it in the configuration file with the related key property?
3. What are client id and client Secret and from where can I get it?

   ```
   @Configuration 
    @EnableAuthorizationServer 
   public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter{
    private String clientid;
   private String clientSecret;      .................. }`
   ```
4. If I use the in-memory database then I can override configure method like this

   ```
   @Override 
   public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory().withClient(clientid).secret(clientSecret).scopes("read","write")
        .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token").accessTokenValiditySeconds(20000)
      .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(20000); }
   ```

If I use oracle database and JPA with userDetailsService then what should be a configure method?